# Sass compiler not working in sublime text 3

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

I have Sass installed on my Windows 7 machine and I'm trying to compile some scss.

Each time, I get the following output:

```
'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['sass', '--update', 'W:\\exocet\\web\\build\\mirror\\css\\style.scss:W:\\exocet\\web\\build\\mirror\\css/style.css', '--stop-on-error', '--no-cache']]
[dir: W:\exocet\web\build\mirror\css]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec\MyWinLocker 3\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec\MyWinLocker 3\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\]
```

What appears to be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thankfully, I found the answer [here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2807-sass-compile-fails)...

> If you are receiving the 'sass is not recognized as an internal or
> external command' error... ...and have Sass installed, you have to add
> it to your system's PATH variable.
>
> At the end of the string, add ;C:\Ruby192\bin.

Instructions for altering PATH variable can be found [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

> Windows Vista and Windows 7 users:
>
> 1. From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
> 2. Click Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
> 3. In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
>
> Windows 2000 and Windows XP users:
>
> The path is now managed by Windows 2000 and Windows XP and not the autoexec.bat
> or autoexec.nt files as was done with earlier versions of Windows.
> To change the system environment variables, follow the below steps.
>
> 1. From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
> 2. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
> 3. In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
>
> ---
>
> Finally, in the Environment Variables window (as shown below), highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon as shown below.
>
> C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32

Note that the numbers "192" given in the example in the first link ( ;C:\Ruby192\bin ) will differ for each version of Ruby.

Comment: Do we have to install Ruby before configuring the environment path?

Comment: I'm not too sure, it's been a while since I installed Ruby, although I'd recommend doing it that way round to be safe

Comment: By any chance would it be possible for you to have a screen sharing session and help me with compilation of SaSS to CSS?

Comment: It is not possible to configure the path if Ruby is not installed, because the folder name of Ruby will not exists.