# How to compile Sass to CSS in Sublime Text 3 automatically?

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

For example, there is package for less **LessToCss**. As for Sass(or SCSS) I don't know what i should do. Ruby and sublime package **Sass** are installed.

Comment: https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css found this one, haven't tried it though

Comment: it for less. i'm need info for sass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to alter the PATH variable at the end of PATH string in the Environment Variables: **Desktop** - **Properties** - **Environment Variables**. It for win vista/7 users. Detail for 2000/XP here [Sass compiler not working in sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115610/sass-compiler-not-working-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to download a SASS build compiler from here: [SASS Compiler](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SassBuilder)
This is automatic Sublime package that simply builds your file at the place.
However since they released the new version, there seem to be multiple settings on this package - you could try to mess with that a bit and see what it can do nowdays.

Second way is to write your own Build command in Sublime. You do this by going to "Tools>Build System>New Build System..."

```
{

    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${project_path}/Project/Web/css/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--style", "compressed", "--no-cache", "--sourcemap=none"],
    "selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }

}
```

Explanation: I use a folder structure as the following: Project/Web/CSS - If you have the Sublime Project FILE at the same level as Project FOLDER, then this will automatically build your Sass file (placed ANYWHERE in the project file) in your Web/CSS folder. Of course you can change this as you see fitting.

Comment: That plugin is only for ST 2.

Answer (score 2):

here is 100% solution, as i also using. Actually i am using in mac so, i am not sure about windows because i wouldn't try yet in windows but i think it will works in window's too.

so here is the build;

copy this from starting brackets and paste it into build and then save with any name like (Build to CSS),"

```
{

    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/../css/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"],

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/user/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": true
    }
}
```

If it's working then please comment.

Thanks